# What is the equivalent of ASP:Timer control in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Recently i am working on migrating the ASP.NET Web application to MVC.

I am wondering if there is any equivalent of ASP:Timer control in ASP.NET MVC Framework. So that this **Timer control** can automatically check for a particular value from the Database once in every couple of Seconds(that we specify).

If there is no **equivalent of Timer control in MVC**, Are there any other ways to implement this.

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a jQuery Timer

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

and activate an ajax call every time the timer triggers

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript setInterval method to invoke an Ajax request and fetch contents from the database.